# Connect the two HTML menu on active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have two HTML menu on my site. First, top-menu. Second, footer-menu.

Top Menu:

```
<ul id=creamenu>
    <li><a id="menu1" href="site1.com">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu2" href="site2.com">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu3" href="site3.com">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu4" href="site4.com">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu5" href="site5.com">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Footer Menu:

```
 <div id="footer-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a id="menu1" href="site1.com">1</a></li>
       <li><a id="menu2" href="site2.com">2</a></li>
       <li><a id="menu3" href="site3.com">3</a></li>
       <li><a id="menu4" href="site4.com">4</a></li>
       <li><a id="menu5" href="site5.com">5</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

This menus have different `active` style and working. I want, connect this menus on active.

E.G. When i click `menu1` on top-menu get active class topmenu and footer-menu. How can i do it?

Comment: first off, you can't have two elements with the same ID

Comment: However, this structure using the script like this.

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna Use classes instead of ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ikopel/8/edit)

**HTML**
(Apply the same class to the `ul` to both the menus)

```
<ul id="creamenu" class="menuHolder">
  <li><a href="1.com">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2.com">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3.com">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="4.com">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="5.com">5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="footer-menu">
  <ul class="menuHolder">
    <li><a href="1.com">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.com">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.com">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.com">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="5.com">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$('.menuHolder li a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menuHolder li a').removeClass('active');
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  $('a[href="' + link + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it's working. Get active class same time but don't go to URL.

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();` to get the links to behave normally. I added that so that it becomes easy for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `id`'s should be unique through out the document you should not have more than 1 object with the same id.  So change your html to use `classes` instead :

```
<div id="top-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site1.com">1</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site2.com">2</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site3.com">3</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site4.com">4</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site5.com">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site1.com">1</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site2.com">2</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site3.com">3</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site4.com">4</a></li>
       <li><a class="menu-item" href="site5.com">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then using jQuery [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method you can add or remove a class as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-item').click(function(){
        $('.menu-item').removeClass('active'); // This will remove active class from other links
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#creamenu a').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var pos = $(this).parent().index();
    $("#creamenu li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#footer-menu li").removeClass('active1');
    $("#footer-menu li").eq(pos).addClass('active1');
});
```